# assign var in for loop

Tags: python, list

I have created the for loop to "extract" column from list of lists, now I want to assign this list to a variable.
How to do it?

I have the following for loop:

```
j = 1
for i in range(len(table)):
    row = table[i]
    print(row[j])
```

and the table looks like:

```
NAME
Bart First
Maria Great
Theresa Green
```

I would like to do some other "operations" on that column and I guess would be easy to use functions if that column is assign to variable...but I have no idea how to do it. (I must not use numpy or pandas for this).

Comment: @martineau whoops, we edited at the same time. It's rolled back to your version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with minmal change of original: create list before loop and append to it i.e.:

```
j = 1
list1 = []
for i in range(len(table)):
    row = table[i]
    list1.append(row[j])
print(list1)
```

Note that you might use `for` to access element directly rather than using index, i.e. loop might be replace with

```
for row in table:
    list1.append(row[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrt *"I guess would be easy to use functions if that column is assign to variable"*: You could use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which is a Python built-in to give these things "names". Essentially, you would be converting each row into a tuple (instead of a list) and each part of that tuple would be accessible by name as well as index instead of just index.

For that you'd first need to assign each row of `table` to a namedtuple. Without more details in your post about what `table` contains, apart from `NAME`, I'll make assumptions about your data:

```py
import collections

# example `table` data
table = [[1, 'Bart First', 30, 'UK'],
         [2, 'Maria Great', 25, 'US'],
         [3, 'Theresa Green', 20, 'PL']]

# the namedtuple "structure" which will hold each record:
Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', 'id name age country')

people = []  # list of records
for row in table:
    person = Person(*row)  # convert it to a namedtuple
    people.append(person)

# or the four lines above in one line:
people = [Person(*row) for row in table]

# or assign it back to `table`:
# table = [Person(*row) for row in table]
```

`people` would now look like:

```
[Person(id=1, name='Bart First', age=30, country='UK'),
 Person(id=2, name='Maria Great', age=25, country='US'),
 Person(id=3, name='Theresa Green', age=20, country='PL')]
```

Next, to get just the names:

```py
all_names = []
for person in people:
    all_names.append(person.name)

print(all_names)
# output:
# ['Bart First', 'Maria Great', 'Theresa Green']

# or as a list comprehension:
all_names = [person.name for person in people]
```

Since you mentioned you can't use pandas or numpy, that would prevent you from doing certain things like `sum(people.age)` or `people.age.sum()` but you could instead do

```py
>>> sum(person.age for person in people)
75
```

And if you still need to use the index, then you can get the `country` data (4th column, index=3):

```py
>>> col = 3
>>> for person in people:
...     print(person[col])
...
UK
US
PL
```